# Location of the spreadsheets when created by the API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

Yesterday I've configured a new project in the Cloud Platform and added the Sheets API to it and made functions to generate access_token to make API calls (in Elixir programming language). Today, when creating a new spreadsheet with the access token, the responde body returns me the spreadsheet and all the info about it, but, when accessing the Drive of the account that I've used on the Google Cloud console to create the new project I can't find the sheet there. Plus, when clicking in the spreadsheet url provided on the response body it prompts me to the Request Access page (when I'm trying to access with the email that holds the project @ Cloud platform).

[image: Access Denied Prompt Page]

So the questions are, **where are the files being stored and how can I access them?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where? it's easy, it's on Google Cloud!! The question is "who is the owner"? The answer is: the service account who has created it! So, I don't know Elixir programming language, but the solution is to make another API call to make you as reader or owner of the created spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey @guillaumeblaquiere I found out what was wrong. I forgot to add the Drive API soo I couldn't find the files and didn't knew I had to add permissions to others emails to access the file through the Drive API (because from the service account email was impossible).